# Is there any algorithm for enumeration of all trees in TREE(3) sequence?

Tags: graph-theory, trees, big-numbers

What is the reasoning leading to conclusion that the TREE(3) is so big?
Is there any algorithm generating all the trees in sequence? I know such algorithm would not finish in meaningfull time, but it would demonstrate how multiple levels of recurrence lead to gross number of iterations.

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate of the linked question. The answer in the linked question provides a lower bound for TREE(3) by providing a long sequence (not necessarily of maximal possible length, in particular if the lower bound is sharpenable), but this question is asking for an explicit construction of a sequence of longest possible length